# Getting errors trying to implement an operator<<?

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and still trying to grasp class implementation with constructors etc.

I have a program split into 3 files,a header file, a class implementation file, and driver file.

In the header file I get an error "explicit type is missing('int' assumed) for this line of code   friend operator<<(ostream &, ARRAY &);

In my class implementation file i get errors for this friend function saying i don't have access to the private members.

And in my driver file I get an error "can't determine which instance overloaded function 'endl' intended" for this code : cout<

I'll leave some of the code below,first is the .h file, then the class implementation file, and then the driver file.
Any help clearing this up is much appreciated.

Header

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class ARRAY
{
public:

    ARRAY();

    ARRAY(int );

    ARRAY(const ARRAY &);
    ~ARRAY();

    friend operator<<(ostream &, ARRAY &);

private:

    string *DB;

    int count;

    int capacity;
};
```

Implementation file

```
#include "array.h"

ARRAY::ARRAY()
{
    cout<<"Default Constructor has been called\n";

    count = 0;
    capacity = 2;

    DB = new string[capacity];
}

ARRAY::ARRAY(int no_of_cells)
{
    cout<<"Explicit-Value Constructor has been called\n";

    count = 0;
    capacity = no_of_cells;

    DB = new string[capacity];
}

ARRAY::ARRAY(const ARRAY & Original)
{
    cout<<"The copy constructor has been invoked\n";
    count = Original.count;
    capacity = Original.capacity;

    DB = new string[capacity];

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        DB[i] =Original.DB[i];
    }

}

inline ARRAY::~ARRAY()
{

    cout<<"Destructor Called\n";
    delete [ ] DB;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, ARRAY & Original)
{
    for(int i=0; i< Original.count; i++)
    {
        out<<"DB[" << i <<"] = "<< Original.DB[i]<<endl;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Driver file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "array.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"invoking the default constructor (11)"<<endl;
    ARRAY myArray;
    cout<<"Output after default constructor called\n";
    cout<<myArray<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"invoking the explicit-value constructor (12)"<<endl;
    ARRAY yourArray(5);
    cout<<"Output after explicit-value constructor called\n";
    //cout<<yourArray<<endl<<endl;


    cout<<"invoking the copy constructor (3)"<<endl;
    ARRAY ourArray = myArray;
    cout<<"Output after copyconstructor called\n";
    cout<<ourArray<<endl<<endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not following the rule of three.

Answer (score 4):

You left off the return type:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &, ARRAY &);
```

Comment: Yeah that was the problem it's perfect now thanks, kind of embarrassing overlooking that but oh well.

Comment: @jim Far from perfect, see chris’ comment: your code violates the rule of three, it thus contains a bug.

Answer (score 0):

as Carl Norum mentioned in his solution

```
You left off the return type:

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &, ARRAY &);
```

also you have remove `inline` from

```
inline ARRAY::~ARRAY()
{

    cout<<"Destructor Called\n";
    delete [ ] DB;
}
```

to be

```
ARRAY::~ARRAY()
    {

        cout<<"Destructor Called\n";
        delete [ ] DB;
    }
```

Comment: No, you can leave `inline` there just fine.

Comment: but when I excute the code getting me an error Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ARRAY::~ARRAY(void)" (??1ARRAY@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main